# Cannot connect through bluetooth in multipeer connectivity iOS 10

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, swift3, multipeer-connectivity

I have developed an application that communicates with nearby devices using multipeer connectivity framework in Swift 3 iOS10 SDK. It works as expected in iPads using only Bluetooth but it doesn't work in iPhones if wifi is set to off, and I want to use only Bluetooth. 
If it is the issue with IPv6 then how to enable it.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The current consensus is this is a bug in iOS 10 (we're in the same boat, it just stopped working.)

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/62306

From Apple via 3rd party in above link (Sep 22, 2016 2:11 AM):

> Engineering has determined that your bug report (28218002) is a duplicate of another issue (28300004) and will be closed.